# jQuery to perform an event when an image is broken

Tags: jquery, image, typeerror, onerror

I found this problem mentioned before here [jQuery/Javascript to replace broken images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92720/jquery-javascript-to-replace-broken-images)

and this was the best answer.. I tried it and it's working fine

```
function ImgError(source){
   source.src = "/images/noimage.gif";
   source.onerror = "";
   return true;
}

<img src="someimage.png" onerror="ImgError(this);"/>
```

but when I tried to preform other events in the previous function

```
function ImgError(source){
   source.hide(); // hide instead of replacing the image
   source.onerror = "";
   return true;
}
```

I got this error

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'source.hide()')
```

Every single jQuery event/method I tried that function I got a TypeError.

What's the problem?

Comment: You aren't using jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `.hide()` is a jQuery element.

Try that:

```
function ImgError(source) {
   $(source).hide();
   source.onerror = "";
   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`hide()` is a jQuery method, yeah?

try `$(source).hide()`

:)

edit: 
you may try adding a global error handler for all images like so:

`$('img').error(function() {
    $(this).hide();
  });`

see:  http://api.jquery.com/error/

Answer (score 0):

did you tried the following:

```
source.style.visibility='hidden';
```